# HttpClient's SendAsync is very slow (Not a Proxy issue)

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Currently, sending a POST message with HttpClient is taking ~600ms.  This seems to be far longer than it should, as sending an identical POST with a C program I wrote inorder to test (using a simple socket) performed significantly better, about 37ms for the same action and significantly more code.

```
sw.Start();
HttpResponseMessage result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
sw.Stop();
```

This was my measuring method.  I am aware that I could be using an async function, and await instead of using the task Result, however there is nothing to worry about "blocking" in this case, and using await/async would be no faster since sending and receiving the messages would take the same amount of time asynchronously.  Atleast, this is my understanding.

Here is an example of its use within a function :

```
    public void makeAttempt(string attempt)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage() { Method = HttpMethod.Post })
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://example.com/page?1");

            request.Content = new StringContent("attempt-" + trys.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            sw.Start();
            HttpResponseMessage result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            sw.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Request took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms");
        trys++;
    }
```

Originally I also had the HttpClient & HttpClientHandler within using blocks in the same statement, however I read that HttpClient is meant to be reused over multiple requests, so I moved them to global scope and initialize them within the constructor, like so:

```
HttpClient client;
HttpClientHandler handler;

    public Test(CookieContainer jar, WebHeaderCollection heads)
    {
        cookieJar = jar;
        headers = heads;
        handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieJar, AllowAutoRedirect = true, Proxy = null, UseProxy = false };
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
    }
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this could be, or how to improve the performance of this operation?  Thank you in advance, and will keep everyone updated on anything I learn!  Cheers!

Comment: You should not be using `.Result`, if you want synconous web methods you should be using `System.Net.WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`. You should switch classes or make `makeAttempt` async and use async/await.

Comment: Why should it make any difference at all?  As I said in my original post, there is no operations to worry about blocking in this case and execution time from start to finish would be identical.

Comment: As requested, I made the suggested async/await changes and it had no noticeable effect on performance unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have backported the .NET Core 2.1 SocketsHttpHandler to .NET Framework and I observed significant performance improvements with the [backported implementation](https://github.com/TalAloni/StandardSocketsHttpHandler) compared to .NET Framework HttpClientHandler in some cases, notably when dozens of multiple requests are issued concurrently.